# How to call json data in selectionchanged event of listbox in WindowsPhone 8?

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I Have two page like news.xaml and subnews.xaml.Each Page has a listbox.In the news.xaml page i have bind listbox with **json** data, i would like to do that when i choose one item of listbox it generate sub list in subnews.xaml page listbox **dynamically with json** data in **selectionchanged** event.
**My first json look like** which is used in get data in listbox of news.xaml page:

[

{
     fid: "1",
     forum_name: "Product News",

},
  {
     fid: "19",
     forum_name: "Supplier News",

}

]

**My second json is look Like** which is used in get sub news:
SELECT id as topic_id, poster, subject FROM bb_topics WHERE forum_id=optionid ORDER BY posted DESC limit 0,20 – .

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Acctully i need that, suppose i choose first item it generate sublist of firstitem, if i choose third item it generate sublist of thirditem, and so on.

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @verdesrobert if you have any idea?

Comment: what problem are you facing??

Comment: My problem is how to fatch fid in selectionchanged event and bind with json2, in which i explained above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on News.xaml.cs

```
// Make Class Object.

GetNews SelectedItem;

private void lstNews_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    try {
        if(e.AddedItems.Count > 0){
            SelectedItem = (GetNews)e.AddedItems[0];
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SubNews.xaml?parameter=" + SelectedItem.fid + "&parameter2=" + SelectedItem.forum_name, UriKind.Relative));

            //reset selection of ListBox
            ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

on subnews.xaml.cs

```
string strgetFId = string.Empty;

string strgetFname = string.Empty;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter2", out strgetFname)){
            txtsubnews.Text = strgetFname;
        }
        if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter", out strgetFId)){
            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted;
            webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("Your URI"));
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try{
        string data = e.Result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)){
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetSubNews>>(data);
            lstSubNews.ItemsSource = root;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

GetSubNews == your class

Answer (score 0):

In the listbox_selectionchanged event, you can get the selected item using the code

> Listbox.SelectedItem

Pass the selected item to your other page using

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourPage.xaml?parameter=" + selecteditem.id, UriKind.Relative));
```

And on the next page, on loaded event, retrieve the parameter and pass it to a function to get json

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter", out Id))
{
    GetJson(Id);
}
```

In the GetJson function, write your logic in which you get json

Comment: @ Hitesh your code is work. But if you able to give eg of passing querystring in next page. I get my selecteditem.fid , i am not know to how to use this id in next page and getdata.

Comment: In the GetJson function, I have passed Id. You can take that Id and use it wherever you want.

Comment: @ Hitesh i am done, but sitll i have one pro how to get this data in listbox.

Comment: bind it the same way you have bind to your listbox on the first page

Comment: My code:protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  string strgetFId = string.Empty;
  if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter", out strgetFId))
  {
     WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
     webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted;
     ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
     webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Config.mainUrl + Config.getNewsTopicList + strgetFId + "/0"));
   }  
}

Comment: private void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
          MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
               
               
                   lstSubNews.ItemsSource = ......;  
               
 }

Comment: yeah, add all the json to your object and bind it to listbox